# Template class partial specialization syntax

Tags: c++, templates

The following basic example of partial template class specialization, taken from [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_template_specialization) :

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
class KeyValuePair { /* something generic */ };

template <typename Key>
class KeyValuePair<Key, bool> { /* something specific to Value=bool */ };

KeyValuePair<int> kvpi;
```

generates a compiler error :

```
prog.cpp:10:17: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)  KeyValuePair<int> kvpi;
```

Why ? what am I doing wrong ?
How a partial template class specialization should be declared and instantiated ?

I am expecting variable `kvpi` to be a partially specialized template class instance of type `KeyValuePair<int,bool>`.

Comment: What do you expect `Value` to be in `KeyValuePair<int>`?

Comment: @TartanLlama: In `KeyValuePair<int>`, I expect `Value` to be `bool`, but I did manifestly not define the partial specialization properly to do so.

Comment: @shrike Partial specialization doesn't work the way you are expecting it to work. You will have to provide both Key and Value type. Only when the value type is bool, it will choose the specialized class implementation, for all other types it will use the first implementation.

Comment: @shrike Sounds like you want a default template argument rather than partial specialization: `template <typename Key, typename Value = bool> class KeyValuePair {};`

Comment: OK, understood, I was confusing partial specialization and default parameter; actually, I need both. Thanks for pointing what was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to be confusing partial specialization with default template arguments. It further appears you need both (for reasons unstated, but not really important). Though not entirely intuitive, it can be accomplished as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Key, typename Value = bool>
class KeyValuePair
{
public:
    KeyValuePair()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << "original\n";
    }
};

template <typename Key>
class KeyValuePair<Key, bool>
{
public:
    KeyValuePair()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << "specialized\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
    KeyValuePair<int,int> kvp1;
    KeyValuePair<int> kvp2;
}
```

**Output**

```
KeyValuePair<int, int>::KeyValuePair() [Key = int, Value = int]:original
KeyValuePair<int, bool>::KeyValuePair() [Key = int, Value = bool]:specialized
```

The confusing part to some is the default argument specification, but a template that follows which will never actually see fruition with that default-arg because of the later specialization. In such cases I prefer to forward-declare the template with its default argument list. At least for me it makes it slightly easier to read. You may (or not) choose to do the same if you feel it offers clarity. Something like:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value = bool>
class KeyValuePair;

template <typename Key, typename Value>
class KeyValuePair
{
public:
    KeyValuePair()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << "original\n";
    }
};

template <typename Key>
class KeyValuePair<Key, bool>
{
public:
    KeyValuePair()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ':' << "specialized\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: I was indeed confusing partial specialization and default parameterization; and I actually need both, just like your snippet illustrates. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Partial template specialization doesn't allow you to forget a template parameter. You have to write:

```
KeyValuePair<int, bool> kvpib;
```

and correct specialization will be used.

But you can use inheritance to achieve what you want:

```
template <typename Key>
class KeyBoolPair : public KeyValuePair<Key, bool> {};

KeyBoolPair<int> kbpi;
```

or if you use C++11 or greater:

```
template <typename Key>
using KeyBoolPairBis = KeyValuePair<Key, bool>;

KeyBoolPairBis<int> kbpbi;
```

example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5095fc5c358d291a

Comment: seams to answer my needs too; will this be equivalent to use of partial specialization in conjunction with default parameter (like in the answer from WhozCraig) ?

Comment: For me, it's not equivalent: developers cannot definitively not use `KeyValuePair` with only one template parameter; they have to use "another" class like. This another class is based (inheritance) or an alias (`using` keyword) of `KeyValuePair`. And in both case, you have to specialized template (ie, have `template<typename T> class KeyValuePair<T, bool>....`). Personnaly, I prefer `using`

Comment: ok, I did not notice that you changed the template class name, which is indeed mandatory; then solution with default parameter will best suit my needs as the name does not change. anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You define your partial specialization correctly, but the template expect 2 argument and you provide only one.

You may use default argument:

```
template <typename Key, typename Value = bool>
class KeyValuePair {};
```

to allow

```
KeyValuePair<int> kvpi;
```

And you may keep your partial specialization if needed

```
template <typename Key>
class KeyValuePair<Key, bool> { /* something specific to Value=bool */ };
```

Comment: OK, understood, I was confusing partial specialization and default parameter; actually, I need both. Thanks for pointing what was wrong.

Comment: @Jarod42: thank for your answer, I indeed need a default parameter, but I also need a partial specialization (ie: implementation of KeyValuePair must be different when instantiated with parameter Key only); add it to your snippet and I accept your answer.